# How to select a dynamically created radio button using code in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular development. I have a webpage which shows a list of car models with a checkbox for selection. 
When user selects a car, it shows color options for that model as a radio button group.

[image]

I'm generating these check boxes (Models) and radio buttons (Colors) dynamically using the below code.

```
<p-table #dtc [columns]="selectedColumns" [value]="tempModelList" [scrollable]="true" ="rank">
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-parentRowData let-columns="columns" let-i="rowIndex">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0rem 0rem !important;" style="width: 95%;" colspan="3">
            <p-table #dt2 [columns]="childColumns" [value]="parentRowData.Models" [paginator]="false">

                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="childColumns" let-j="rowIndex">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0.440rem 0rem !important; width: 2% !important;">

        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0.440rem 0rem !important;width: 30% !important; text-align: left;">

            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="rowData.isSelected"
                [id]="rowData.modelKey" name="ItemChecked"
                (change)="OnModelSelected(rowData,$event)">
            <label *ngIf="rowData.isSelected" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">
                {{rowData.modelDesc}}</label>
            <label *ngIf="!rowData.isSelected"> {{rowData.modelDesc}}</label>

        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0.440rem 0rem !important;width: 67% !important; text-align: left;">
            <span style="padding: 0rem 0rem !important; text-align: left; " *ngIf="rowData.isSelected">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" [checked]="rowData.prefColor=='Red'"
                    name="{{rowData.modelDesc}}" value="Red" (click)="OnColorSelected(rowData,$event)" />
                <label for="y">Red</label>
                <input type="radio" class="radio" [checked]="rowData.prefColor=='Black'"
                    name="{{rowData.modelDesc}}" value="Black" (click)="OnColorSelected(rowData,$event)" />
                <label for="y">Black</label>
                <input type="radio" class="radio" [checked]="rowData.prefColor=='White'"
                    name="{{rowData.modelDesc}}" value="White" (click)="OnColorSelected(rowData,$event)" />
                <label for="y">White</label>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

The code works fine. But my requirement is..

> When user selects a model the color **White** should be selected
> automatically as a default option.

User may change the color later, but to avoid number of clicks I want to select a default color. When the default selection happens the code associated with the radio button click OnColorSelected() should also get executed.

```
//On the Model checkbox selected.
OnModelSelected(rowData,event){
  var row = rowData;
  var selectedModel = rowData.modelDesc; //Selected Model

  //Now I need to select radio button White from the radio button group with name <selectedModel>
}
```

Since the controls are created dynamically I found it very difficult to get references and make the selection. Please can someone help.

Thanks